# Non-volatile UDF always recalculating

Tags: vba, excel-2010, user-defined-functions, volatile

I am trying to make a non-volatile UDF but it seems not possible. So here is a my very simple test-UDF:

```
Option Explicit
Dim i As Integer

Sub Main()

i = 0
[A1] = "zyy"
MsgBox i

End Sub

Function Test(rng As Range)
Application.Volatile (False)

Test = rng.Value
i = i + 1

End Function
```

I got a otherwise empty worksheet that uses this function a couple of times, and every time I call Main() and change any cell on the sheet with the UDFs all of them recalculate. How can I make this (any) UDF no-volatile? The Application.Volatile (False) should have that effect but obviously doesn't work.

Edit: If I change a cell manually it works like intended, it only recalculates when I change a cell via VBA. Is this normal behaviour or can I change it?

Comment: I don't know *why*, but try removing `Application.Volatile False` from your function.   When I test this, that gives the expected result (msgbox displays 0 **unless** some instance of `=Test(_range_)` on the worksheet refers to `A1`.

Comment: And, in Excel 2007, msgbox displays 0 unless rng is equal to A1, even with the Application.Volatile (False) statement

Comment: Removing Application.Volatile doesnt help, still everything gets recalculated when I change anything via VBA. That is strange... Can this be due to some setting?

Comment: I thought to check both the `Application.Calculation` (which has no effect on this situation) and also to check the order of events and see if this was triggering the sheet's `_Calculate` event, but I don't think that was it, either.  If you manipulate a cell value from the Immediate window (instead of from a subroutine), what happens? (for me, it does not re-calculate the function).  (this is not an answer, just trying to make sure we're seeing the same thing happening.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, and it is indeed a very simple one but also made this hard to debug:
If you make any change to your VBA code all the UDF get flagged for recalculation!
I modified the degug code of David:

```
Sub main()

'nothing depends on the Value in [A13]
[A13] = "" 
[A13] = "hgdg"
[A13] = ""
i = 46

End Sub

Function f_appvol(rng As Range)

Application.Volatile
Debug.Print "f_appvol"

f_appvol = rng.Value
End Function

Function f_appNOTvol(rng As Range)
Application.Volatile (False)
Debug.Print "f_appNOTvol"

f_appNOTvol = rng.Value
End Function

Function f_omit(rng As Range)

Debug.Print "f_omit"
f_omit = rng.Value

End Function
```

After entering the code and running it for the first time, only f_appvol is recalculated. If you now change i=46 to i=47 and execute it, all the UDF get recalculated. All subsequent runs after that first run after the change give the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 12):

I am posting a new answer instead of trying to salvage my previous answer, even though I think they point to the same thing, it will be better to start fresh.

**Background:**

Previously I had tested your code and the results were exactly as I would expect them to be if you simply omit the `False` from that statement. I have never seen any reason to explicitly do `Application.Volatile (False)`, because that is equivalent to simply omitting the statement entirely.

- If omitted, the function is non-volatile and the UDF evaluates *only* when a reference changes (i.e., **not** when other, non-referent cells change)
- If included as `Application.Volatile` (or `Application.Volatile
  (True)`, the UDF becomes volatile and any change to the worksheet
  will force re-evaluation.

**Continuing investigation**

You commented that you still observed otherwise. So I made some changes to my code and tested again.  All of a sudden weird stuff was happening. No matter what I did with the `Application.Volatile` function, **any** change to the worksheet was re-evaluating the UDF.

This didn't make sense, so I started googling and doing a little more testing.

In my tests I created three functions.

1. The first one is explicitly Volatile:
2. The second one is explicitly **not volatile**.
3. The third omits any statement of volatility.

I put one instance of each formula on a worksheet. Each referenced a different range.

[image]

I tested each of these by making changes to the worksheet (manually), and through a named subroutine. I used a `Print` statement and monitored the Immediate window in the VBE to confirm that in all cases, the functions evaluated (or not) only as expected. The first one *always* evaluates, while 2 and 3 only evaluate if reference range changed.

```
Function f_appvol(rng As Range)

Application.Volatile
Debug.Print "f_appvol"

f_appvol = rng.Value
End Function

Function f_appNOTvol(rng As Range)
Application.Volatile (False)
Debug.Print "f_appNOTvol"

f_appNOTvol = rng.Value
End Function

Function f_omit(rng As Range)

Debug.Print "f_omit"
f_omit = rng.Value

End Function
```

**Then it got weird...**

I started making changes within these functions and they start to behave wonky.

Specifically I got lucky and noticed that if I changed my non-volatile function to a volatile one, then all functions started acting as if they were volatile -- even the `f_omit`. I believe this may be the condition you are experiencing.

**Somehow, we have managed to "confuse" Excel**

I saved the workbook and tried again... back to normal!

Then I changed the argument in the volatile statement, and the strange behavior happened again.

**This appears to be a bug**

I don't see anything [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195441%28v=office.15%29.aspx) that suggests this is normal/expected behavior, and it sure as hell is not *desirable* behavior from a debugging standpoint. This is the sort of thing that makes you pull out your hair in frustration!

I am using Excel 2010, Win 7 64b.

**Resolution**

The cause of the error seems to be making change to the volatility of a UDF.

In order to restore expected behavior, it seems necessary to save the workbook.  Again, I don't think this is normal but it seems to solve your problem (or at least a very similar problem that I was able to replicate while troubleshooting yours).

**On a possibly related note**

There appears to be at least one bug related to volatility, as mentioned [here](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/false-volatility-is-this-a-bug/). I link to it mainly because this writer echos my own sentiment: there is no reason to do `Application.Volatile (False)` because that is (or should be) the "normal" state of a UDF.

> I have to admit that I had never seen the point of using Application.Volatile False since thats supposed to be what you get if you omit the `Application.Volatile` statement altogether.

Comment: I was expecting that Debug -> Compile VBAProject would have fixed the issue, but no, only a save and re-open of Excel does the trick. Even a change to a comment will introduce application volatility again...

Comment: Note that excel suggests that the default value for `Application.Volatile` is `True`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile)